# Enable a PHP folder within a Rails app?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ajax, apache, .htaccess

I need to run some scripts written in PHP in a Rails app through some JS ajax calls. I am having a cross-domains issue where my scripts are active on localhost/scripts and my app is active on localhost:3000/myapplication. Ajax requests to localhost return a cross domain error.

I was able to implement the jsonp workaround, and it works fine but I would ideally like to access the php file from within the rails folders. I read that its possible to configure the apache server to enable PHP on a folder within the framework. I am running Apache2 on Linux.

[Attempted solution](http://blog.hulihanapplications.com/browse/view/27-running-php-inside-a-rails-app)
I'm not 100% sure where to find the .htaccess file, so I just made one in the directory (public/php-scripts). Not sure if that works though...

Attempt 2: 
I can't seem to configure my server correctly:
I installed all the passenger components and modified my file as so: /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.1.3/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.1.3
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myservername
        DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/public

        <Directory /var/www/myapp/public>
                Allow from all
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/

        <Directory /var/www/>
          Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
        <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And I restarted the server. What am I missing ? 
I navigate to myservername/ and myservername/myapp and get a Forbidden message

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried [passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) with apache.

This should help you.

http://www.abletech.co.nz/blog/serving-php-from-a-rails-app-with-passenger

key to this is to disable the Passenger for a specific route.

This works for me

Put this lines in 
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default or /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file (I am not an expert at server configuration so decide one, I had this in httpd.conf)

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.1.3/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.1.3
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myservername
        DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/public

        <Directory /var/www/myapp/public>
                Allow from all
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
  # route for php app im my example /blog
  Alias /blog /var/www/blog  
  <Location /blog>
    PassengerEnabled off  
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can't get past the apache config. Help?

Comment: @cearto, regarding forbidden check if the server has rights to access files , this should be file system permission  issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my config for nginx server with php-fpm.

You need add the "passenger_enabled off;" in the php location block so  all php files inside the /public will work fine.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.rails-site.com;
  root /var/www/rails_site/public;
  access_log logs/www.rails-site.com.log combined;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_min_instances 10;
  rails_env production;
  client_max_body_size 150M;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    passenger_enabled off;

    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```